# Inserting a space in between characters using gsub - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Let's say I had a string "I have 36 dogs in 54 of my houses in 24 countries".
Is it possible by using only gsub to add a " " between each digit so that the string becomes "I have 3 6 dogs in 5 4 of my houses in 2 4 countries"?

`gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, "#{$1} #{$2}")` does not work as it replaces each digit with a space and neither does `gsub(/\d\d/, "\d \d")`, which replaces the each digit with `d`.

Comment: You should replace the word "number" with "digit". Why the rush to select an answer? By doing so you may discourage other answers and it may not be appreciated by those still preparing answers when the greenie flashes on. There's no rush. I suggest you wait at least a couple of hours.

Comment: Are you only concerned about substrings having two digits? That would seem very odd. If substrings could have more than two digits, what would you want returned? If, for example, the string were "123 dogs", would you want "1 23 dogs", "1 2 3 dogs" or something else returned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to reference a match you should use `\n` where `n` is the match, not `$1`.

```
s = "I have 36 dogs in 54 of my houses in 24 countries"
s.gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, '\1 \2') 
# => "I have 3 6 dogs in 5 4 of my houses in 2 4 countries"
```

Comment: I don't know ifthe OP wants `"I have 365 dogs".gsub(/(\d)(\d)/, '\1 \2') => "I have 3 65 dogs"` or `"I have 3 6 5 dogs"`.

Comment: True, but that was not part of his specification, therefore I did not take any decision on it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Let's say it did want "3 6 5". How would _you_ go about doing that?

Comment: @c650, I assumed that was wanted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "I have 3651 dogs in 24 countries"
```

Four ways to use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

**Use a positive lookahead and capture group**

```
r = /
    (\d)   # match a digit in capture group 1
    (?=\d) # match a digit in a positive lookahead
    /x     # extended mode

s.gsub(r, '\1 ')
  #=> "I have 3 6 5 1 dogs in 2 4 countries"
```

A positive lookbehind could be used as well:

```
s.gsub(/(?<=\d)(\d)/, ' \1')
```

**Use a block**

```
s.gsub(/\d+/) { |s| s.chars.join(' ') }
  #=> "I have 3 6 5 1 dogs in 2 4 countries"
```

**Use a positive lookahead and a block**

```
s.gsub(/\d(?=\d)/) { |s| s + ' ' }
  #=> "I have 3 6 5 1 dogs in 2 4 countries"
```

**Use a hash**

```
h = '0'.upto('9').each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s] = s + ' ' }
  #=> {"0"=>"0 ", "1"=>"1 ", "2"=>"2 ", "3"=>"3 ", "4"=>"4 ",
  #    "5"=>"5 ", "6"=>"6 ", "7"=>"7 ", "8"=>"8 ", "9"=>"9 "} 
s.gsub(/\d(?=\d)/, h)
  #=> "I have 3 6 5 1 dogs in 2 4 countries"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to look for the place between the numbers using lookahead and lookbehind and then just replace that with a space.

```
[1] pry(main)> s = "I have 36 dogs in 54 of my houses in 24 countries"
=> "I have 36 dogs in 54 of my houses in 24 countries"
[2] pry(main)> s.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/, ' ')
=> "I have 3 6 dogs in 5 4 of my houses in 2 4 countries"
```